# Why is total pressure calculated by integrating force and not by direct integration of pressure?

Tags: pressure, integration

While calculating the total pressure acting on a body (precisely, we are asked to calculate total pressure [average pressure?] acting on a body submerged underwater), the general procedure is that we find a suitable differential element, find out the total force on that element, integrate to get the total force on the body and divide it by the surface area.

---

An incorrect method, for which I have no explanation, is as follows. Forgive me for using the submerged body example since that is the problem I'm facing difficulty in.
To calculate the total pressure acting on a submerged body, we should be able to integrate `ρ*g*dh` where `dh` is the height of the differential element. Right?
[This is an example](http://www.mechanical-engineering-assignment.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/63.png)  of the differential element I am talking about here.

My intuition says that I can not integrate pressure directly since it is a tensor, not a scalar. But I am not sure about my reasoning.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. Total pressure and average pressure do not seem to be useful quantities. For what purpose are you calculating them? Can you provide an example in which you are asked to calculate total pressure? – sammy gerbil 6 mins ago

Comment: The question in class was to calculate the total pressure acting on the face of a rectangular plate submerged in water.

Comment: Surely you mean the total *force* acting on the plate? Calculating the total *pressure* is like calculating total *temperature*. It has no meaning.

Comment: I don't, don't you calculate the hydrostatic pressure on a submerged plate?

Comment: Yes if the pressure is the same all over the plate, eg when the plate is horizontal. But not if the pressure is different at different points on the plate, eg when the plate is vertical.

Comment: "Calculate resultant hydrostatic pressure on the slab in the vertical plane." Exact question.

Comment: That does not make sense. I suggest you discuss this with your teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an entirely incorrect method. While pressure is part of rank-2 tensor, this calculates the pressure exerted on the object due to the mass above, so you are calculating only one of the components of the tensor.

So for $\vec{n}$ being the normal to surface A, assuming both $\vec{n},\vec{F}$ point to the opposite directions: $p=\frac{\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}}{A}=-\frac{mg}{A}=-\frac{\int_C\int_a^bρg*dh*dA}{A}$ and then integrating the top by dA, while g and h do not depend on A: $p=-\frac{(\int_CρdA)\int_a^b g*dh}{A}$.
One would come to the conclusion that the integral of dA will give us the average volumetric density over a surface of the cross section and thus: $p=-<ρ>g*dh$

In another way, One can also easily show that, again after a vector product of normal with the force:
$$p=-\frac{F}{A}=-\frac{\int_a^b F*dx}{\int_a^b A*dx}$$
Since A is the surface area over the y-z plane:
$$p=-\frac{\int_a^b F*dx}{V}$$
The term in the numerator is the definition of work. For gravity:
$$p=-\frac{\int_a^b mg*dx}{V}$$
By definition $\frac{m}{V}=<ρ>$ and thus:
$$p=-\int_a^b<ρ>g*dx=-\int_a^b<ρ>g*dh$$
Let's redefine the equation for the pedants among us. If you know your statistics, the pressure we would get would be an average over a surface area, so, with a subscript A denoting the average is over a surface area: 
$$<p>_A=-\int_a^b<ρ>_Ag*dh$$

In the general case however if you want to use a mass density that is not averaged over a cross section, for example if you want to know how a certain surface would deform for non uniform pressure gradient, then:
$$p(y,z)=-\int_a^bρ(x,y,z)g*dx$$

The average density is used in cases, such as fluid dynamics, to find the static pressure due to gravity where density is usually uniform. In other instances the external forces are not necessarily uniform, say a hammer laying on a desk, and that's when an average density would not suffice.

So in a way, the equation calculates an average pressure over the surface if density is the average.

As to "total pressure", either it is a slip of a tongue, typo or you misheard "total force". Pressure is an intensive quantity like temperature, it can differ from point to point, but it can't be accumulated, unless of course it is directly related to something else that accumulates.

Comment: The last paragraph cleared stuff, but then, I have been asked to calculate total hydrostatic pressure on a rectangular slab submerged underwater. Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: If each point over dh contributes a small amount of pressure, then yeah, it can be said that it would be 'total pressure from all the points applying said force' if you want to be accurate.

Comment: In this case, the "total" pressure that is being talked about is the"average total" pressure right?

Comment: Average over a surface area, yes. You are in a way integrate mass over on axis rather than pressure, and said pressure depends on the mass